# Importing a function creates the whole object

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I'm trying to unit test a generator function from Saga, like this:

```
import { foo } from '../mySaga'

describe('bla', () => {
  it('bla bla', () => {
    expect(foo('bar')).toEqual('baz');
  })
})
```

But when I run it, it goes to the default function of `mySaga` as if the whole object is created, this causes errors of course.

And it happens even if I just import the Saga file without using it in the test.

PS: Eventually, I'll test the iterator itself but even a basic call to a saga function fails

Comment: how are exporting the functions?

Comment: export function* foo(action) @supra28

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not testing the generator properly, you'll have to do something like this:

```
import { foo } from '../mySaga'

describe('bla', () => {
  it('bla bla', () => {
    let testFoo = foo('bar')
    return expect(testFoo.next().value).toEqual('baz');
  })
})
```

Comment: I did that first, it still happens.

Comment: Can you add what errors you are getting to the question?

Comment: They wouldn't tell you much because they're specific to the project, we have an include that happens in the index.html file instead of adding it to the package.json, because of that it's undefined in testing. That include comes from one of the includes that the saga is doing but it's unrelated to the function I'm trying to test.